# Display public keys + fingerprints of Dropbear SSH server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, public-key, dropbear

While I normally use OpenSSH I have Dropbear installed on a Debian system to provide a small SSH server for unlocking disk encryption during initramfs boot phase.

Dropbear and OpenSSH have different formats key files. I also don’t want them to share the key pair and not convert Dropbear’s key pair to OpenSSH.

How to just display Dropbear’s *public* key in the OpenSSH format and/or its fingerprint?

Answer (score 2):

Dropbear uses a binary format for storing the key and has no second file for storing the public key, especially not in a human-readable form.

The program `dropbearkey` is responsible for key generation but will also display the public key for the binary key file. The `-y` switch is **important** for *reading* the file, not *writing* it!

```
$ sudo dropbearkey -y -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_ecdsa_host_key
Public key portion is:
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHA1MjEAAAAIbmlzdHA1MjEAAACFBAFygHJYm8rXlIrktbgGEcrfkipydP7ZM+mkWwot7lhnrYYuKvwMNE99YyvrKYT8fXnVaemSgOsigJDGAgdfCyJNjgDdNE4AU4RQRY4IN4PinnlMsw2Lv1BY1q+F2IcBBoSb/2OVTc2c5/LRQ7/rbPcqBpU8V3v67CTTULYY7yH1BTfnXQ== root@hostname
Fingerprint: md5 7d:c5:7e:43:a2:07:c3:93:a7:fe:5c:76:60:2e:a0:4c
```